# Dump firmware from MC9S08EL32 MCU

Tags: firmware, hardware, memory-dump, dump

I have a [datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7s5Y0TSnlYfd2Z5bUFLOVdQMzQ/view?usp=drivesdk) of the HCS08 micro-controller family from NXP. I have a Raspberry Pi and some time. I admit that this is my first time delving this deep into hardware RE, so be gentle with me.

I got the damn thing to spit numbers out at me, so I know that the chip has a serial output at least. And, I have the chip mounted on a breakout board and I have a breadboard handy. Also, let's assume security bit is not set (*fingers crossed!!!*).

I try to get out the firmware to a file.

Any help would be appreciated, even a couple links and a tip or two for my specific case if you could!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look at the [USBDM project](http://usbdm.sourceforge.net/) which claims to support BDM ([background debug mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_debug_mode_interface)) for the RS08 and HCS08 series, among others, which I *think* should be compatible with your chip.

Even though they talk about Codewarrior, in theory the source code should allow you to implement your own code dumping tool.